# How to disable shortcuts for QComboBox in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

I searched for the answers online, but I did not really find one that solved my problem. My question is like: I have a `QComboBox`, let's say I added three items to this:

```
ui->comboBox->addItem("First");
ui->comboBox->addItem("Second");
ui->comboBox->addItem("Third");
```

Then if I press the `S` on the keyboard, the item will change to `Second`, if I press `T`, so item will just change to `Third`. 
How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to implement an `eventfilter` that prevents the letters from being used in the `QComboBox`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class Helper: public QObject{
    QComboBox *m_combo;
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    void setComboBox(QComboBox *combo){
        m_combo = combo;
        m_combo->installEventFilter(this);
    }
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){
        if(m_combo){
            if(m_combo == watched && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress){
               QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
               if(!ke->text().isEmpty())
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QComboBox w;
    w.addItems({"First", "Second","Third"});
    Helper helper;
    helper.setComboBox(&w);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```